# Where can you get grants for children going to Yeshiva / Seminary in Eretz Yisroel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, money, chinuch-education, yeshiva-school

Does anyone know where can you get grants for children going to Yeshiva / Seminary in Eretz Yisroel?

Comment: Check your local Foundation

Answer (score 4):

[MASA](http://www.masaisrael.org/Masa/English/) will give grants to those going to certain yeshivos.

Answer (score 2):

- [The Alisa Flatow Memorial Scholarship Fund](http://www.alisafund.org/index.aspx?page=1) has been around for a while. They award a handful of scholarships competetively.
- The school[s] you're interested in may have a financial aid program.